# CSS: how to propagate width from photo to parent or grandparent element?

Tags: html, css, image, aspect-ratio

I'm putting together an image gallery with captioned images of varying aspect ratios.  For uniformity, I want the browser to render each image at the same height, computing the width to preserve the aspect ratio.  But I seem unable to figure out how to propagate this width to the width of the caption.

My HTML looks like this:

```
<div class="photo">
  <a href="images/name.jpg">
    <img src="thumbs/name.jpg">
  </a>
  <div class="caption">Imagine long caption here</div>
</div>
```

And here's one of my many attempts at CSS:

```
div.photo {
    margin: 5px;
    float: left;
    height: 7cm;
    margin-bottom: 3cm;
}

div.photo img {
    display: block;
    max-height: 7cm;
    width: auto;
}

div.caption {
    padding: 15px;
    text-align: center;
    display : block;
    width: 90%;
    overflow : auto;
}
```

Here's what I think I'm accomplishing:

1. Fixed height on the `photo` element puts everything at the same height.
2. Bottom margin on the `photo` element makes room for the caption.
3. Given `max-height` and `width: auto` on the image preserves aspect ratio.
4. On the caption, `text-align` and `display` properties have the caption centered and wrapping properly.

Here's what I'm not accomplishing:

- The `photo` element gets wide enough that many captions are much wider than their containing photos, especially when the photo is a "narrow portrait" 9:16 aspect ratio.

I would really like to avoid writing a program that probes every image to discover its aspect ratio and then forces the width of the containing element manually.  Is there a way to get CSS to set the width of an element to match the width of an image contained in a descendant?

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the variant below. You can set the width of the figure to auto and it should resize correctly this time. Hope this helps!
The HTML:

```
<figure class="photo">
<img src="photo.jpg">
<figcaption>
Caption goes here.
</figcaption>
</figure>
```

The CSS:

```
figure {
    display:table;
    margin:14px;
    padding:7px;
}
figure.photo {
    float:right;
}
```